# ASP.NET Membership & GridViews

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-membership

I have a site using ASP.NET Membership and have a number of roles that users are assigned to. One feature I really want to do is to be able to programatically add the "edit" or "delete" buttons to rows in a GridView, based on the role the user is a member of.  For example:

If the user is an admin I want to show the edit and delete buttons on the gridview, but if they are an editor, to just show the edit button.  I know this is possible as I have seen an example done before, but can't for the life of me find it in my bookmarks!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the "[RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)" event for your gridview, and inside your event handler, check the user's credentials and set the appropriate visibility on your buttons.

```
void MyGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{  
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      // Check user credentials and set button visibility
      e.Row.Cells[x].Controls[y].Visible = true; //or false
    }
}
```